# How to iterate through each cell in a worksheet range and unlock them based on a Regex match

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2015, openxml, closedxml

I have tried and failed to find the syntax for a function to loop through each cell in a worksheet and match its address to a Regex, and unlock the cell based on a positive match, but it seems that IXLCell addresses cannot be cast to Strings?
This is the function I have been working with:

```
Private Function NeedsToBeUnlocked(cell As IXLCell) As Boolean
    Dim returnValue = False
    Dim address As String = CType(cell.Address, String)
    Dim reg As Regex = New Regex("^B5|[CDEFGH][56]|H9|[CDEFGH]12|[CDEFGH]4[5-9]|[CDEFGH]5[012]|[GH]6[6-9]|[GH]78[0-7]|[GH]88|[GH]9[0,6-9]|H1[47]|H2[1278]$|H3[01347]|[BCDFGH]16[246]|[CDEFGH]15[789]|[CDEFGH]160|E16[24]|[GH]10[0-9]|[GH]11[012]|G129|[GH]13[01]|H11[789]|H12[012,6-9]|H13[289]|H14[0-5,78]$")
    Dim match As Match = reg.Match(address)
    If match.Success Then
        returnValue = True
    End If
    Return returnValue
End Function
```

and this is the For Each loop.
Clearly the syntax is incorrect but you get my drift.

```
For Each c As IXLCell In xlWS.Range("A1", "I177").Cells
    If NeedsToBeUnlocked(c.Address) Then
        c.Style.Protection.SetLocked(False)
    End If
Next
```

This is my naive attempt to not just use a series of direct statements like this. There must be a better way?

```
xlWS.Range("B5", "H5").Style.Protection.SetLocked(False)
xlWS.Range("C6", "H6").Style.Protection.SetLocked(False)
xlWS.Cell("H9").Style.Protection.SetLocked(False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach without using RegEx would be to define an array of ranges and loop over these:

```
Dim ranges As String() = { "B5:H5", "C6:H6", "H9", ... }

For Each range as String in ranges
    xlWS.Range(range).Style.Protection.SetLocked(false)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you question correctly, but a way to loop through a cells I often use is:

```
For ic 1 to 5         ' i column - in range from A to E
    For ir 1 to 20    ' i row
        wSheet.Cells(ir, ic).Value = "Col=" & ic & "  row=" & ir
    Next ir
Nect ic
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `NeedsToBeUnlocked` function is declared with a parameter of type `IXLCell` but you call it with a parameter of type `IXLAddress`. Change your call to

```
If NeedsToBeUnlocked(c) Then
```

And to get the address of the cell as a string in the function change

```
Dim address As String = CType(cell.Address, String)
```

to

```
Dim address As String = cell.Address.ToString()
```